# MonoGame on iOS (init texture from internet)

Tags: monogame

I'm developing a game on iOS with Monogame. Is it possible to init a texture2D with images downloaded from the internet? If so, is there any samples I can follow? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this maps 1 to 1 with iOS, but here is how I did it on Android MonoGame. Most of this code came from another post on Stack, but unfortunately I can't remember the post!

```
/// <summary>
/// Downloads a texture based on a URL path, and stores it in this sprites texture.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="URL">The path to the file.</param>
private void DownloadTexture(String URL)
{
    HttpWebRequest request = HttpWebRequest.Create(new Uri(URL)) as HttpWebRequest;

    request.BeginGetResponse((ar) =>
    {
        HttpWebResponse response = request.EndGetResponse(ar) as HttpWebResponse;
        using (Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream())
        {
            using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
            {
                int count = 0;
                do
                {
                    byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
                    count = stream.Read(buf, 0, 1024);
                    ms.Write(buf, 0, count);
                } while (stream.CanRead && count > 0);

                ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

                /*Texture2D*/ mTexture = Texture2D.FromStream(GameObjectManager.pInstance.pGraphicsDevice, ms); //.PreMultiplyAlpha();
            }
        }
    }, null);
}
```